# web dynamic form with options that will decide the set of fields being displayed?

Tags: .net, angular, forms, reactjs, vue.js

What should be the best approach to create a web dynamic form with options that will decide the set of fields being displayed?

This form will have common fields and fields that are specific to a combination of previous answers. I calculate 120 different possibilities of forms.
The form will be included in a .net mvc solution.

Specifically, I would like to know if Angular, React, Vue.js or other should be considered and which will be more effective and fast to implement.

Comment: Yes, any of the three will do the job, but which to choose depends on your use case, app architecture and team knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React and Angular are both viable solution, I do not know deeply Vue.js but I think it is a valid solution too.
For React take a look to the redux-form mechanics (models are generated per-form-template-base)